# Failed to generate C++ Coverage file with bazel on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, code-coverage, bazel

#### Description of the problem / feature request:

> 

I am doing some coverage test on bazel-example project,  but I failed to get coverage file:

- build project with coverage related options

`git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/ bazel_examples`

`cd bazel_examples/cpp-tutorial/stage1`

`bazel build -s --copt="-coverage" --linkopt="-lgcov" //main:hello-world`

The result shows build command runs successfully, but **no coverage files(*.gcno) are generated**.

Then I run the binary output, **but no runtime coverage files(*.gcda) are generated too**.

I am using bazel 3.5.0, gcc 9.4.0,  Ubuntu 18.04.5.

Does any one know how to resolve this?

Comment: Check `man gcc`, the option should be named `--coverage`, with two minus signs. However, `bazel coverage` should be your go-to tool, it should do the rest for you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try checking the coverage by running the below command.

```
    bazel coverage -s \
  --instrument_test_targets \
  --experimental_cc_coverage \
  --combined_report=lcov \
  --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main \
  //...
```

You can find the coverage file here

> bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat